# Python. Certain XPath expressions not working

Tags: python, xml, xpath, web-scraping, xpath-2.0

I've been expermenting with XPath through Python.

The thing is that not all the expressions work.

I have just found the **XPath helper** chrome extension.

As you see Chrome detects the XPath, but Python doesn't.

The website : [link](/html/body/table[@class='center'][2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td)

[image: Xpath detected]

My code :

```
import __future__
from lxml import html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://directory.ccnecommunity.org/reports/rptAccreditedPrograms_New.asp?sort=institution')
soup = str(BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser'))


tree = html.fromstring(soup)
smth = tree.xpath('/html/body/table[@class="center"][2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/text()')

print(smth)
```

`smth` list is empty. Why? It should have consisted of all the `td`s I indicated in the Xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow it getting annoying to get the same problem again and again with only slightly different questions.
 The problem is ( and this will not changes) that the html on the page is completely broken. So you need to start to accept  that the DOM interpretation is different between browser, lxml or BeautifulSoup. I suggest to save the `soup` string to a file an try to figure out what BeautifulSoup did with the broken html. 
With that you may figure out what (if any) the right xpath may be.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is using `tbody` as part of the selector, when no `tbody` tags exist in those tables. Your browser is filling in `tbody` sections when it renders the page because they're a required part of the spec, but if you view the source you'll see they don't actually exist.

Don't trust what the browser sees. Especially if you have javascript enabled. You'll often end up with pages where the element tree is nothing like your simple `requests.get()` will see.

Comment: That means that the html is broken??? How can I fix it...

I thought the `html.parser` argument from `BeautifulSoup` will fix this.